# Cities and Countries : One matches and others don't

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

"So here is a table of five cities and five countries",  said Grandpa.

"With my logic, one city is perfectly matched to the country in the same row. Other four are not. Can you rearrange those four cities so they are a perfect match with the countries?" He asked.

I looked at the table. Did not make sense to me. Does it to you? Can you get the match? What logic was he using?

[image: table of place names, see transcription below]

TEXT for the Table

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| NAIROBI | SINGAPORE |
| WARSAW | POLAND |
| AGRA | TURKEY |
| BEIJING | BELARUS |
| KABUL | SOMALIA |

Comment: If there is no significance to things like fonts or table rules (lines) in an image, please provide a _text_ representation of the table. Some idiotic corporate netnanny systems block i.stack.imgur.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correctly matched pair in this puzzle is *not* the capital-country combo of WARSAW and POLAND, contrary to what you might expect. Instead, it is:

> BEIJING and BELARUS

The others should be paired up as follows:

> NAIROBI and SOMALIA
>  WARSAW and TURKEY
>  AGRA and SINGAPORE
>  KABUL and POLAND

Why? Because:

> The cities all begin with **the symbol of an element in the Periodic Table**, while for each of these there is a matching country name which begins with **the first two letters of the element's full name**:
>
>  **Be**/**BE**RYLLIUM : **Be**IJING and **BE**LARUS
>  **Na**/**SO**DIUM : **Na**IROBI and **SO**MALIA
>  **W**/**TU**NGSTEN : **W**ARSAW and **TU**RKEY
>  **Ag**/**SI**LVER : **Ag**RA and **SI**NGAPORE
>  **K**/**PO**TASSIUM : **K**ABUL and **PO**LAND
>
>  The Periodic *Table* connection also explains why these items are presented as a *table*!